# Getting Excel to process Access 2013 application method/functions not in Excel

Tags: excel, function

MS Access has some built-in functions (such as Nz()) that Excel does not recognize.  Is it possible to add Access Application.methods to Excel?

I am attempting to create a data connection from an Access Query (or View) to Excel (Office Pro Plus 2013).  I was successful connecting a query with a calculated field: ABS([Credit]), but was unsuccessful connecting a query with Nz([Credit]).  Excel has the built-in function ABS(), but not Nz().  I assume if Excel could "process" the Nz() function, I could make a data connection to a query with the Nz() function in it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use all VBA functions in all programs.

But you have to make sure that the Office 15.0 (Office 2013) library will be loaded (Under MS Visual Basic (Alt+F11), select Tools - References...) and set a checkmark.

Sometimes you need further libraries which you can select.

Comment: From the VBA Object Browser in Access, I located the Nz() function as a method of Access.Application object.  Clicking on "Access" shows the location and file: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\MSACC.OLB.  Following your instructions, I add MSACC.OLB as a library in VBA in Excel.  

Two problems: (1) Excel does not save MSACC.OLB as a loaded library, which suggests it conflicts with an pre-loaded Excel library object. (2) Excel's list of functions does not include the likes of Nz().

Comment: @user3042202; I don't know how you could use the function direct in an excel cell. I think you have to write a small vba function to use it. You have to define a Access Application Object. Look here for more details [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/hh211481%28v=office.14%29.aspx)